# Helm - Is it possible to add quotes to all items in a list on its template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let's say I'm creating a helm template in which I want the eventual deployments to be able to execute a command to their liking. For this example, I'll use use the `touch` command.

In my templates file, I'd write it down like this:

```
templates.yaml

...
foo:
{{- if .Values.foo.command }}
  exec:
    command: {{ .Values.foo.command }}
{{- end }}

...
```

Then following that, I'd have my values file:

```
values.yaml

...

foo:
  command: ["touch", "bar.txt"]

...
```

When I'm checking the resulting template of the above, the command gets templated as:

```
foo:
  exec:
    command: [touch bar.txt]
```

Thus, there are no quotes/commas in its command. Would this still execute as intended? Or are commas and quotes necessary in order for this to execute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work as expected.  The output syntax you show is a valid YAML list, but only containing a single shell word, and so it is looking for a command named `touch bar.txt`, where the space would be part of the filename in `/usr/bin`.

The Go text/template engine that Helm uses isn't especially aware of YAML.  When you directly write out a value like this, it uses a default formatting that's not especially useful.  Helm has a couple of lightly-documented extensions to write out values in a more useful format.  For your example I might use:

```yaml
foo:
{{- with .Values.foo.command }}{{/* like "if", but also rebinds `.` */}}
  exec:
    command:
{{ toYaml . | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
```

This should write out:

```yaml
foo:
  exec:
    command:
      - touch
      - bar.txt
###### note: 6 spaces here matches `indent 6`
```

You may be able to fit `command: {{ toJson .Values.foo.command }}` into a single line.  In either case it may not have the exact formatting that's in the `values.yaml` file, since Helm parses the YAML at startup time and then writes out the equivalent structure.